# No module named 'ortools.graph.pywrapgraph'

Tags: python, or-tools

I am getting this error in Google Colab while doing 'from k_means_constrained import KMeansConstrained'. I got the same error when I tried to run the same import command from the command line. The problem is with 'pywrapgraph' it seems as ortools.graph is working fine

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: its not working, could you try it once and let me know

Answer (score 4):

Solve the `No module named 'ortools.graph.pywrapgraph'` error message by installing ortools version 9.3.10497 with the following command:

```
python3 -m pip install --user ortools==9.3.10497
```

Then import ortools and ortools.graph.pywrapgraph:

```
import ortools
import ortools.graph.pywrapgraph
```

Comment: Even after upgrading ortools and importing, its the same error- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ortools.graph.pywrapgraph'

Comment: I am able to import graphs from ortools but not pywrapgraph. Ultimately I want to import KMeansConstrained from  k_means_contrained and it can only be done once pywrapgraph is imported

Comment: Did you try to run the import commands from the command line to eliminate the possibility that the error message was caused by whatever Python IDE or Python virtual environment that you are using (if any) and not by your Python code?

Comment: Yes, I just tried that: same error

Comment: Where were you running the import commands from before?

Comment: in google colab

Comment: I suspect that your problem is that Google Colab doesn't have some package that it needs. I recommend installing whatever packages that you need locally and testing your import statements locally before moving your code up to Google Colab.

Comment: I think the problem pertains to this bug
https://github.com/joshlk/k-means-constrained/issues/28

Comment: Can someone have a look and please let me know how to fix it, thanks

Comment: It is indeed an issue with the new version of ortools. I installed the previous version ortools==9.3.10497 and now it got resolved

Comment: if you have already installed ortools, try to uninstall ortools package by python -m pip uninstall ortools then install ortools==9.3.10497

Answer (score 3):

The issue should be resolved with the latest version of `k-means-constrained`. Please update the package using `pip install 'k-means-constrained>=0.7.2'`. This works, but seems to require Python 3.8+ now.

Comment: This works, but seems to require Python 3.8+ now.

Answer (score 1):

To allow a using numpy to speed up the setup of the graphs used in min_cost_flow, max_flow, and linear_sum_assignment, I have switched the wrapping from SWIG to pybind11.

The new modules are:

- ortools.graph.python.linear_sum_assignment
- ortools.graph.python.max_flow
- ortools.graph.python.min_cost_flow

Sorry missing the change in the 9.4 or-tools release notes.

Comment: Why did you not vectorise `set_node_supply` and obtaining the results like `flow`?

Comment: Oops :-) Done with https://github.com/google/or-tools/commit/f69de028ba8341f5ed061507d367445fd0225f07. It should appear in 9.5. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while trying to install k-means-constrained on a kaggle notebook. The following sequence worked for me. Note that the ortools version is further back than the one suggested by [karel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1940850/karel).

```
! pip install k-means-constrained
! pip install ortools==9.3.10459
import ortools
import ortools.graph.pywrapgraph
from k_means_constrained import KMeansConstrained
```

Comment: For me, I had to downgrade the release as well: `pip install k-means-constrained==0.6.0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import ortools.graph.pypywrapgraph
```

changed to:

```
from ortools.graph.python import min_cost_flow

smcf = min_cost_flow.SimpleMinCostFlow()
smcf.add_arcs_with_capacity_and_unit_cost()
```

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/optimization/flow/mincostflow?hl=id

Answer (score 0):

Run:

!pip install ortools

Then continue with your code.

example: from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp